# Cannot inherit with generics

Tags: c#, generics

This class declaration:

```
public abstract class Repository<TE, TD>
    where TE : class, IEntity, new()
    where TD : DataProvider<TE>
```

Cannot be fulfilled by this class signature:

```
public class SqlRepository<TE> : Repository<TE, SqlDataProvider>
    where TE : SqlEntity, new()
```

Where `SqlEntity : IEntity` and `SqlDataProvider : DataProvider<SqlEntity>`, I get this error:

> Error  1   The type ~ cannot be used as type parameter 'TD' in the generic type or method '~.Repository'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '~.SqlDataProvider' to '~.DataProvider'.

Why can it not convert the SqlEntity to the interface it implements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is what in `SqlRepository<TE>` you are fixing `TD`'s inner generic parameter, which is linked to `TE` in `Repository<TE, TD>` declaration, to be `SqlEntity` but this cannot be told about `TE`, which is left generic.

What you can do, is keep `TD` generic in `SqlDataProvider` like this:

```
public class SqlDataProvider<TD> : DataProvider<TD> 
    where TD : SqlEntity
```

and then surface this dependency in `SqlRepository` like this:

```
public class SqlRepository<TE> : Repository<TE, SqlDataProvider<TE>>
    where TE : SqlEntity, new()
```

This compiles, because `TE` usage is consistent.

Comment: Also worth reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue.  However, the reason I didn't want to use a generic for the SqlDataProvider class was because I wanted to use the singleton pattern.  This causes a warning when using the generic since it does not like static fields in a generic-using class and I would prefer that there be only one instance of data provider being hit by compilation rather than implementation.  is this possible, or will I simply need to leave a strongly worded comment?

Comment: I'm not getting how you could use this to enforce a singleton. Could you update your question with relevant code and description of the intent?